# How to restore the special playlist in foobar2000 that shows all songs selected in Album List?

Tags: foobar2000

When I first installed foobar2000 years ago, there was a feature I really liked - one of the playlist tabs reflected live whatever is selected in the Album List panel. For example, if you clicked on "Radiohead" in the album list, this playlist would automatically contain all Radiohead songs. If you clicked one of the album sub-trees of Radiohead, the playlist would update to show just the songs from that album.

Also, if you type a phrase in the Filter box below the Album List, you can make the playlist automatically contain all the tracks that match.

I'm not sure when this playlist feature disappeared, but I have since reinstalled foobar2000 a few times and I can't get the feature back. I've tried Googling but I'm not sure what the feature was called.

Any ideas?

---

**Update**: I found the setting, thanks to searching terms provided by afrazier. It is called **Library viewer selection playlist** (which is in Preferences: Media Library).

Answer (score 4):

Look for a checkbox in the preferences labeled album selection playlist, iirc.

You might want to look into the [facets component](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_facets) too. It's very nice for browsing through your collection and introduces the old autoplaylists functionality.

From Foorbar 2000 FAQ:

> **Why is Autoplaylist Manager no longer maintained?** In foobar2000 0.9.5
>   or newer, you can create autoplaylists by right-clicking an Album List
>   branch. In order to create a query-based autoplaylist using Album
>   List, use the 'filter' box to enter a query and create an autoplaylist
>   from the 'All Music' item.